# Many same input -> form to one request / many forms to many requests?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, semantic-markup

I'm working on `<form>` that have multiple groups of `<input>` with the same attributes `name='product-code'` and `name='amount'` (because of structure).
For better understanding, example: form where you can choose color and amount of one specific product to add in a basket, but I want to send product code from the catalog (because each color of this product is another item in a catalog) instead of sending color names.
And I'm trying to understand how it should be done semantically correctly and serialized. Should it be one form and one post request or many forms and many post requests? What's your opinion?

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="product-code" value="ST912600">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="product-code" value="ST821806">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="0">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="product-code" value="ST467165">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="product-code" value="ST348499">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="product-code" value="ST545081">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="0">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="product-code" value="ST430287">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="0">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="product-code" value="ST988144">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="4">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I'm expecting the server will parse request with multiple data as an array

Comment: You should not use the same name for multiple inputs, try using a suffix, like a number, and iterate it in your JS before posting to the API.

Comment: @DannyG can you add a short example of your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same name in `form` tag. Visual your form like an associated array.

```
name => value
name2 => value2
```

So if you send a form with the same name, you create a conflict.

But you can use a simple form, change `name` attribut like you want and set a class named product-code for example. `preventDefault` with JS on your submit button and use `getElementsByClassName` and get his value etc. save in an array and create a loop for submit one by one with `formElt.submit()` funtion.

Or create a lot of forms in HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this (`product-code2`, `amount2`, `product-code3`, `amount3`). But I think it's a bad practice to send this type of urlencoded data. And what if I have 999 products' inputs? `product-code999`? And what about length of the parser code on the server side then?

Comment: You don't need to use an incremental list like product1,2,3 etc.

Comment: Oh, I had a wrong meaning after reading that suggestion. I reread and now I see the point. Still, I want more opinions or point of view on this question

Comment: Oh sorry ! This comment is not the full version ! I press enter to fast lol and i forget edit after 5 minutes...

Comment: I want to say that : you can use a loop for all child of you form and send one by one with AJAX. Or you can use multiple forms but i think the first solution are the best pratice.